# Accessing widget's parameters in _prepareLayout

Tags: php, magento

I'm writing a custom widget for Magento. I have it successfully configured - file `ABC/DEF/Resources.php` is loaded and executed.

```
class ABC_DEF_Block_Resources extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface{
    protected function _prepareLayout(){
        var_dump($this->getData());
    }
}
```

When included in a static CMS block via

```
{{widget type="def/resources" res="css:test.css"}}
```

everything works fairly well returning

```
array(2) { ["type"]=> string(15) "def/resources" ["res"]=> string(11) "css:test.css" }
```

However, when included via `CMS->Widgets` (`Block Reference: Page Top`), the result is

```
array(1) { ["type"]=> string(15) "def/resources" }
```

Any way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used via `CMS` >  `Widgets`, widgets are created with layout instructions, and all the specific data are set using `action` nodes (see `Mage_Widget_Model_Widget_Instance::generateLayoutUpdateXml()`), which are executed after the block is created (so after the call to `_prepareLayout()`).

In your case, you may rather want to use `_beforeToHtml()` (as do some of the base Magento widgets).